# Problem when reverse copying keyframe for walk cycle

Tags: animation, armature

Whenever I try to flip the first keyframe of my walk cycle it turns the pose into a wonky mess instead. I did some reading and figured that its something to do with bone axis alignment but i cant figure out how to fix it. Thank you in advane for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alignement is set by "Roll" property. You can access it in *Edit Mode* on your armature, on property panel <kbd>N</kbd>, for each bone.

[image]

You can also change roll on multiple bones, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

[image]

In order to use correctly Mirror copying, if your Left bone has a X° roll, your right bone must have a -X° roll.